# Product consultation with the prices and sizes

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I have a table with my products of this type:

```
<?php

/** some code */

class Catalogo
{
    private $id;

    private $product;

    /**
    * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Unidades", mappedBy="catalogo", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
    */
protected $unidades;
}
```

(obviously I deleted the annotations and code that is not necessary)

And other related table containing the above measures in the products and the prices are traded.

```
<?php

class Unidades
{
    private $id;

    private $medida;

    private $precio;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Catalogo", inversedBy="unidades", cascade = {"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="catalogo_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $catalogo;
}
```

I have to bring all products with corresponding measures and prices, but not how. I would have to do something like this :

```
product1: 
        measure       price
        measure       price
        measure       price

product2: 
        measure       price
        measure       price
        measure       price

productN: 
        measure       price
        measure       price
        measure       price
```

to make it more real:

```
sand: 
            5 KG          $5
            10 KG         $10
            20 KG         $20

cement:
            5 KG          $7
            10 KG         $10
            20 KG         $12
```

can you help me?? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use the getter

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
$catalog = $em->getRepository()->findAll() 

foreach($catalog as $product) {
  $price       = $product->getPrecio();
  $measurement = $product->getMedida();
}
```

I've added the loop above but you should be able to pass the `catalog` variable through to your view and loop through it there.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html